# Error importing react components from NPM package in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I'm trying to publish my first package to npm for learning purposes. I've created a few react components with typescript and have published them to npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pirate-ui).

And here's the `ts.config` I used for building and compiling the package:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This worked fine, but the problems occur when trying to use these components in my NextJS app using `npx create-next-app@latest`. After initializing everything and successfully `npm install pirate-ui@1.0.5`, I cleared out the src/pages/index.tsx file to get rid of the boilerplate and tried implementing the components like this:

```js
import { TextInput } from 'pirate-ui';
import { useState } from 'react';

interface StateValues {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export default function Home() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState<StateValues>({
    val: '',
  });
  return (
    <TextInput
      name="testing"
      id="my-id"
      curState={val.val}
      raiseState={setVal}
      styles={{ div: '', label: '', input: '' }}
    />
  );
}
```

VScode's autocomplete works, and i'm able to see the props and type defs for the component, and am not experiencing any typescript errors. However, upon running `npm run dev` I get this error:

```
error - /Users/sailormetz/Development/Web/testing-pirate-ui/node_modules/pirate-ui/index.js:1
export { TextInput } from './TextInput';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
```

It's throwing an error on the export statement in my index.js file. Why is this happening? For what its worth, I followed this tutorial [here](https://blog.fildon.me/publishing-typescript-react-components-to-npm).

Feel like I'm doing something silly, or getting something wrong in my ts.config.

Thanks.

Comment: You set `"module": "es6", moduleResolution": "node"`['node' for Node.js’ CommonJS implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution:~:text=%27node%27%20for%20Node.js%E2%80%99%20CommonJS%20implementation). Try to resolve es6 module with something other than CommonJS resolution.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is this because I need `module: "CommonJS"` for `moduleResolution: "node"`? I read the docs and it mentions that "node" strategy is used vast majority of the time.

Can you explain a bit more about this setting and why it wasn't working?

Comment: I guess a more general follow up question would be: given a nextjs project with a ts.config, how config my npm package to be compatible with it?

Comment: Yep. CommonJS modules need 'node'. es modules('pirate-ui') need not Commojs module resolver. Error states: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` - `moduleResolution": "node"` does not expect `export` since CommonJS does not understand es5 syntax. 
`"node" strategy is used vast majority of the time` - if you doing backend development where your runtime is Node.js

Comment: Nextjs is famously known his zero-config setup. I bet it should work out of box