# How can I make my package compatible with my NextJS project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I published an npm package that has a few typescript components. I had some trouble importing them into my NextJS v.13.1.6 app, until someone in my [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517234/error-importing-react-components-from-npm-package-in-nextjs) helped me fix my package's `ts.config`. Now it works. However, I'm left even more confused about the `module` and `moduleResolution` options in the `ts.config`, and I have a general question that I'd kill for an answer to.

**Given any React or NextJS project, what steps can I take to figure out what the `ts.config` options for my package should be?** How can I work backwards from my project specs to get the config right?

Here's what I landed on for NextJS 13.1.6 with TS:

```json
// ts.config for npm package

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I dont really understand, however, why this works. If my project uses import syntax over require, why would my package modules resolve to CommonJS?

Thanks.